# The multipart identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have created a query below but i dont understand why i am getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "fi.FacetsImportId" could not be bound. (For each field)

```
INSERT INTO [Elig].[dbo].[ErrorTable]
(
    [SeqId],
    [CodeId],
    [SubjectArea],
    [FieldName],
    [TableName],
    [ErrorValue],
    [ActiveFlag]
)
Select 
    [fi].[FacetsImportId] AS [SeqId],
    @InvalidLength AS [CodeId],
    @SubjectArea AS [SubjectArea], 
    FieldName,
    'Facets.FacetsImport', 
    ErrorValue, 
    '@ActiveFlag'
From (
    select [fi].[FacetsImportId]
    ,Case When len([fi].[FacetsData]) > 200 Then [FacetsData] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [FacetsData]
    ,Case When len([fi].[DataIndicator]) > 4 Then [DataIndicator] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [DataIndicator]
    from Facets.FacetsImport) [fi]
Unpivot (
    ErrorValue for FieldName in ([FacetsData], [DataIndicator] )) as x
where x.ErrorValue <> 'CorrectValue'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your subselect doesn't alias Facets.FacetsImport.  This should work, note that I took out the aliasing of the subselect.  Doesn't look like it was necessary:

```
INSERT INTO [Elig].[dbo].[ErrorTable] ( [SeqId], [CodeId], [SubjectArea], [FieldName], [TableName], [ErrorValue], [ActiveFlag])
Select [fi].[FacetsImportId] AS [SeqId],
    @InvalidLength AS [CodeId],
    @SubjectArea AS [SubjectArea],
    FieldName,
    'Facets.FacetsImport', 
    ErrorValue,
    '@ActiveFlag'
From ( 
    select [FacetsImportId],
        Case When len([FacetsData]) > 200 Then [FacetsData] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [FacetsData],
        Case When len([DataIndicator]) > 4 Then [DataIndicator] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [DataIndicator]
    from Facets.FacetsImport
) [fi]
Unpivot (ErrorValue for [et].FieldName in ([FacetsData], [DataIndicator] )) as x
where x.ErrorValue <> 'CorrectValue'
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for ur reply. i tried that before but it gives this error : The type of column "DataIndicator" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: @Programmer: sounds to me like it thinks data indicator is one data type and FacetsData is a different data type. Of course, the real question I have is where does [et] come from. Is this your whole query?

Comment: Hi, i took that out. its not in the query. it was just a mistake. Both FacetsData and DataIndicator are having datatype varchar.

Comment: @Programmer: Do they have the same size?

Comment: no. FacetsData is Varchar(200) and DataIndicator is Varchar(4)

Comment: @Programmer: There is your problem.  In order to unpivot them they have to be the exact same thing.  You'll need to fix this by convert[ing] it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You need [fi] aliases inside `AND` outside the subquery.  Change one line in your query

```
    from Facets.FacetsImport [fi]) [fi]
```

For this though `FacetsData is Varchar(200) and DataIndicator is Varchar(4)`, change 1 more

```
,Case When len([fi].[DataIndicator]) > 4 Then convert(varchar(200), [DataIndicator]) Else 'CorrectValue' end as [DataIndicator]
```

But then that begs the question, when will the test

```
len([fi].[DataIndicator]) > 4
```

ever return true for a varchar(4) column??

Comment: Hi @cyberkiwi, thanks for ur response. the field DataIndicator may have invalid records and i have to capture the one with lenght greater than 4.

Comment: You just indicated that it is varchar(4). The max length can only be 4, so how can it happen?